# TwitteR R package how to create friendships (follow=true)

Tags: r, twitter, package

I would like to know if it's already possible to create a friendship
request with a method like create_friendship (id=...) ?
I don't know how to write it in R.

This is what I tried :

```
url.create.friendships <- "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json"
parametres <- "follow=true&user_id=MY_FRIEND_ID"
twitCred$OAuthRequest(URL=url.create.friendships,
                  params=parametres)
```

R return this :

```
Error: Authorization Required
```

NB : twitCred is OK (handshakeComplete = TRUE) and I can use all functions
of the package like `searchTwitter()`

Comment: Does anyone have anything to add to this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
library("twitteR")
library('base64enc') #to correctly authenticate
library("httpuv")
setup_twitter_oauth("xxxxx","xxxxxxxx")
friendships(screen_names = c('user1', 'user2'))
```

This returns a data frame of the users and their friendship status (whether you follow them or they follow you).

Comment: I think the question is how to create a friendship, not to get a data frame of existing friendships